# How to find if a cell contains a substring Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA function

```
Function .....
..........
If (IsNumeric(x) And ((x = "*9999999*") = False)) Then
.......
Else
...........
End If
End Function
```

I need to know if a string contains a substring "9999999". 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If Instr(x, "9999999") > 0 Then ...` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `Like` Operator.

```
Sub test()

Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String

str1 = "dhfjd9999999dfda"
str2 = "ddsss999dfdfsfd"


MsgBox str1 Like "*9999999*"
MsgBox str2 Like "*9999999*"

End Sub
```